# AWS Storage Gateway file share and locking files

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-storage-gateway

We're investigating our options of using a Storage Gateway file share instead of our own cloud infrastructure.

We're having trouble getting it to work. Our Server side application requires locking files while working with them. So far it seems a NFS share would not be able to do that. When we create a SMB share in AWS we can lock files that are created by the user that mounts the SMB share, but we can't lock other existing files. ICACLS shows that we have RW access to files we create but only RX access to existing files. Is there a way to configure this so that we have RW access to all the files on the SMB share on the storage gateway?

Using ICACLS to modify or take ownership of the files on the SMB share just gives an Access is denied error.

Comment: We tried the solution suggested here: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=869016 
1. Delete the SMB file share
2. Create NFS file share & Update the file/folder permissions.
3. Delete the NFS file share
4. Create SMB file share

But that didn't work for us.

Comment: We ended up creating a new bucket and starting from scratch, since that was an option during our testing, but this is a bit worrying.